What happens to a good Muslim during judgement day if he already knows he’s going to jannah?
If a Muslim dies and his soul is taken out in the pleasure of Allah (as oppose to the wrath) and he is then able to answer the 3 questions in the grave correctly, what happens to him on judgement day? Does he have to go through the gruelling punishment of the day?
